# Django-tinymce full featured in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, tinymce, django-tinymce

I set up django-tinymce to work with admin just like the docs described

in settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ ..., 'tinymce',]
```

in models I added

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
content = HTMLField()
```

and in urls

```
urlpatterns = [ ...., url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),]
```

But I can not figure out how to add icons and plugins !
I did a lot of research and I could not find anything useful.

I need a [Full Featured](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/) editor.

Comment: Where are your js (query, bootstrap.js) links in your Base.html? If your page is loading the tinyMCE js links before jquery it won't run. I had a similar problem using redactor wsyiwyg editor. Check your page source and see which one loads first.

Comment: you need to [customize](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration)  it more, lie @whieronymus said, you are missing a bunch of configuration in your `settings.py`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TINYMCE is great. But at times, it fails to send input back to the server.

One of the alternatives to TINYMCE is django-summernote, which is easy to setup and use.

Check django-summernote here:
https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I was looking for ! 
Works like a charm and easy to configure and well documented !

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some configurations settings .py

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'http://debug.example.org/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
```

this is the example given in the docs...try it out
http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: I did what you said, everything seems to work fine except that I can't add any more plugins, like emotions and iframes, if I add them to the plugins, they do not show up.
how can I add them ?